# CMake with Qt to include modules xmlpatterns

Tags: qt, cmake

I am trying to switch from QMake to CMake. I get my first error like this:

```
Target "aacmakeqt" links to target "Qt::xmlpatterns" but the target was not found.
Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

I wonder how to know or find the name of the module? Why it is `find_package(Qt5Widgets)` but not `find_package(Qt5widgets)`?
Why it is `target_link_libraries(project Qt5::Widgets)` but not `Qt5::widgets` or `Qt5Widgets`? Where can I find these information? And the most important is how to use link the [Qt XML Patterns](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxmlpatterns-index.html)?

My .pro file in QtCreator

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-11-07T19:23:43
#
#-------------------------------------------------   
QT       += core gui xmlpatterns widgets

TARGET = myapp
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp ......... 
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h ........
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui ........
RESOURCES += resources.qrc
```

My CMakeList File

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

## Setting ProjectId by current directory
get_filename_component(ProjectId ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
string(REPLACE " " "_" ProjectId ${ProjectId})
MESSAGE(STATUS "\tProjectId: " ${ProjectId} ) ## Debug Message

## Defining project
project(${ProjectId})
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# Find the library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Xmlpatterns)

MESSAGE(STATUS "Project Source Directory: " ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ) ## Debug Message

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_CPP ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)
MESSAGE(STATUS "\tsource: " ${SRC_CPP}) ## Debug Message
add_executable(${ProjectId} ${SRC_CPP})

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(${ProjectId} Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(${ProjectId} Qt5::xmlpatterns)
```

**Solution:**

With a more detailed error message provided by `find_package(Qt5XmlPatterns REQUIRED)`, I understanding CMake cannot find either `Qt5XmlPatternsConfig.cmake` or `qt5xmlpatterns-config.cmake`.

The required `.cmake` files should come with Qt. It turns out that my Qt directory is located in my home directory rather than `\usr\lib`. (I don't know how this happen. I should have install Qt with default options.)

So, I simply help cmake to locate the correct directory. In my case, all the `.cmake` files for Qt located under `~/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake`.
Base on the document for [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html), it searches `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` `CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH` `CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH` for packages in turn. So I just add

```
set(CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH ${CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH} "~/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake")
```

for it to search correctly.

Finally, we can find the name of the package under `Your_Qt_Install_directory/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/lib/cmake"`.

Comment: Can you try `XmlPatterns` instead of `xmlpatterns` (note the casing)? In this case I suspect it's most like Qt following the CMake casing conventions.

Comment: I did try all sorts of casing combination `Xmlpatterns`, `XmlPatterns`....

Comment: What's the output of the CMake run? I asuume it does not find Qt5Xmlpattern. I thought you have to look for `
find_packages(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets XmlPatterns)` or similar.

Comment: For things not mentioned in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html , I think your best bet is to read the source of the FindQt* scripts.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Right. There is not many examples regarding Qt5 with CMake on the net.

Comment: Well, there's all of KDE using CMake+Qt, for starters. They might have added further convenience macros around these things though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
find_package(Qt5XmlPatterns REQUIRED)
```

and then

```
target_link_libraries(name Qt5::XmlPatterns)
```

You had wrong case in the `find_package` too. The `REQUIRED` catches that.

Comment: `REQUIRED` does nothing but print an error message in more detail if the package cannot be found. It is not compulsory to be here. But thanks for your comment, I get the reason why I cannot find the package. I will put it in my question ASAP.

Comment: Yes. `REQUIRED` points you to your first error because of the case incorrectness. Even for optional dependencies, I use `REQUIRED`, and only remove it before pushing.