# Target "ColorCorrector" links to target "Qt5::Quick" but the target was not found

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

I am trying to run a Qt project in CMake environment. After solving compiling errors I have been trying to solve a CMake error that I am quoting below:

**Target "ColorCorrector" links to target "Qt5::Quick" but the target was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?**

**Target "ColorCorrector_lib" links to target "Qt5::Quick" but the target was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?**

The same errors I am getting for the following targets: 
**"Qt5::Sql"**, **"Qt5::XmaPatterns"** as shown also in the attached print screen:

[image: Targets errors: Qt5::Sql - Qt5::XmaPatterns - Qt5::Quick]

Below the CMakeList.txt file I am working on:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
project(colorCorrector)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package( Boost COMPONENTS system thread filesystem REQUIRED)
find_package ( Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick Sql XmlPatterns Xml )

###
### make sure we use c++11
###
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

###
###boost include stuff (required for all libcam)
###
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

###
### QT stuff (required if you want a GUI)
###
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)  
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)  

find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5PrintSupport)

#find all the qt UI stuff
file(GLOB UI
    "ui/*.ui"
)
#make them into headers
qt5_wrap_ui (UI_HDRS  ${UI})

###
### add all your non QT sources
###

# find all non ui sources
file(GLOB SRCS
    "src/*.h"
    "src/*.cpp"
    "src/*.hpp"
)

# find all ui related sources
file(GLOB UI_SRCS
    "ui/*.h"
    "ui/*.cpp"
    "ui/*.hpp"
)

###
### Add executables
###

add_executable(colorCorrector main/main.cpp ui/qdarkstyle/style.qrc ${SRCS} ${UI_HDRS})
target_link_libraries (colorCorrector libCam Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Quick Qt5::Sql Qt5::XmlPatterns Qt5::Xml ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS}  Qt5::PrintSupport)

###
### Add Library
###

add_library(colorCorrector_lib SHARED ui/qdarkstyle/style.qrc ${SRCS} ${UI_HDRS})
target_include_directories (colorCorrector_lib PUBLIC "src/" "ui/")
target_link_libraries (colorCorrector_lib libCam Qt5::Widgets Qt5::PrintSupport ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} Qt5::Quick Qt5::Sql Qt5::XmlPatterns Qt5::Xml)
```

I am looking at different possible solutions such as here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863374/how-to-use-cmake-file-glob-srcs-with-a-build-directory) I looked and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806344/cmake-with-qt-to-include-modules-xmlpatterns?rq=1) is also useful but still didn't solve my problem.

Additionally I tried to add the following according to CMake documentation to the CMakeList.txt file mentioned above:

```
find_package(Qt5Sql)
find_package(Qt5XmlPatterns)
find_package(Qt5Quick)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5PrintSupport)
```

Any idea on what the problem could be?

Comment: What OS? And when you remove CMake cache (or start build into other empty folder) does CMake configure stage complain about something?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and CMake 3.9. I tried removing CMake cache but it does the same "target" problem. Yes it complains because it can't find Qt5::Quick, Qt5::Sql, and Qt5::XmaPatterns

Comment: You are using QtCreator... let open on start page Examples and find&open some Quick example. Try to compile it.
Or try link only Qt libraries into executable (remove ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} etc.)

Comment: Removing {Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} in a certain sense worked partially, but now I have the following error:_Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5XmlPatterns" with any of the following names: Qt5XmaPatternsConfig.cmake qt5xmlpatterns-config.cmake. Add the installation prefix of "Qt5XmlPatterns" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5XmlPatterns_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Qt5XmlPatterns" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed src/clolorCorrector/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)_

Comment: it is pointing to the CMake file I uploaded above specifically at the line 6: `find_package (Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick Sql XmlPatterns Xml)`

Comment: good, it's ok; then you should check if DEB with missing module is installed (libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev package?? sorry, I'm RH developer)

Comment: I installed all dependencies for XmlPatterns, Sql and Quick from this [list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508503/whats-the-development-package-for-qt5-in-14-04)  but still doesn't compile. I don't know if I am missing something.

Comment: The same output or something changed??

Comment: Same output `cannot find -lQt5::Quick` `cannot find -lQt5::Sql` `cannot find -lQt5::XmlPatterns`